# What is the Namespace prefix for doors next generation , the source type URI , the link property in OSLC in?

Tags: namespaces, uri, prefix, oslc, concourse-resource-types

I want to know the Namespace prefix for doors next generation, if I wanna do an integration for requirement management tool for doors next generation in another application, and for the yellow area what is the Namespace prefix for doors next generation and the domain prefix and resource type uri, and finally the link property in OSLC

Thank you and here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03GNs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

DOORS should use `oslc_rm` prefix and the resources specified under it: http://docs.oasis-open.org/oslc-domains/oslc-rm/v2.1/oslc-rm-v2.1-part2-requirements-management-vocab.html